# AzureML Pipelines: Share code across components?

Tags: azure-ml-pipelines

Is there a way to share code among AzureML Pipeline Components? Our use case is that many of our components use the same helper function. We put the helper function in its own directory and were hoping to have each component import it as a module.

We are using the v2 Pipeline SDK where the code directory is specified in a yaml file- things we've tried so far:

1. Adding a list instead of just a single directory

   ```
   code:
     - ../../component_dir
     - ../../shared_utils
   ```

   This resulted in a parsing error when creating a component from the yaml file
2. Specifying the parent directory in the yaml file

   code: ../../

   This resulted in extremely long wait time when running the pipeline (there are many directories/files in the parent dir)